# How to Properly Organize Widgets in Flutter for a Specific Layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, ui-design

I'm currently working on a Flutter application where I need to organize various widgets within a screen. I've experimented with different approaches but haven't been able to achieve the desired layout. Specifically, I'm trying to replicate a design that involves a combination of icons, text, and animation, but the alignment and positioning of these elements do not meet the design requirements.

Here is a snippet of my current implementation:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              //<---here
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: 600,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                ),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: const [
                            Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble,
                                size: 40, color: Color(0xffD6D6D6)),
                            Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.squareXmark,
                                size: 40, color: Color(0xff404040)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 60, 15, 0),
                        child: Stack(   
                          children:  [
                            
                             Center(
                               child: Text(
                                "We send you an Email",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                ),
                                                         ),
                             ),
                             Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Divider(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),
                            ),
                             Text(
                             
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                              child: Divider(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      RiveAnimation.asset(
                        "img/letter_and_knife.riv",
                      ),
                    ],
                    
                  ),
                ),
                
              ),
              
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried using a `Column` widget for vertical arrangement, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Can someone suggest how to structure the widgets to achieve a layout similar to the second design mentioned? Additionally, I'd like to incorporate a specific pink color with `Color(0xffF4CFDD)` in some parts of the layout.

Any guidance or suggestions for widgets and properties that might be better suited for this task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't `Column` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong widget, instead of `stack`, you need to use `column` like this:

```
BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: 600,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffF6F6F6),
                    ),
                    child: LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: const [
                                Icon(Icons.check,
                                    size: 40, color: Color(0xffD6D6D6)),
                                Icon(Icons.close,
                                    size: 40, color: Color(0xff404040)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 60, 15, 0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "We send you an Email",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                                  child: Divider(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Please, check your Email inbox to log in and start using Pomoworko",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                                  child: Divider(color: Color(0xff3B3B3B)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[image]